# Windows Python Program Restarts (Sins in a different life)

Tags: c++, python, windows, cython

I have a very strange Python bug, possibly even a bug in the interpreter.
My minimally reproducing code looks somewhat like the following:

```
from sys import stdout
print "Starting"
stdout.flush()

from camera import py_SaperaCamera
print "Imported"
stdout.flush()

cam = py_SaperaCamera.Camera()
print "Constructed"
stdout.flush()

del cam
print "Destructed"
stdout.flush()
```

I can think of about 1e6 reasons that execution of this program might not go so smoothly.  In fact, I could algorthimacally generate that many!  A few are provided below for your amusement, but feel free to skip to the punch line:

1. During the import of my custom Cython module py_SaperaCamera
2. As a result of initializing or deleting the object which controls my device
3. Segfaults, memory errors, getting killed by the operating system for being naughty
4. Lightening, power outages, the second coming.  Whatever!

I would really love it if execution were to be halted in some way, perhaps a segfault, a loving message from boost::whatever asking me to contact the application support team, hell even if it just stopped and printed nothing.  This would be stellar.

No. Instead I get the following output:

```
Starting
Imported
Constructed
Starting
Imported
Constructed
Starting
Imported
Constructed
Starting
Imported
Constructed
Starting
Imported
Constructed
Starting
Imported
Constructed
```

The attentive reader will note, that the program appears to have been run 6 times, a clear  mark of the beast.  So my question is simply put, what did I do in my previous life to deserve this happening?

Comment: Also worth noting it looks like "Destructed" never gets printed. Is this correct?

Comment: Indeed.  In the actual application I get some more log messages, but really no matter what happens in there, I wouldn't expect to see it start over.

Comment: How are you running this? If you're just doing `py.exe myscript.py` in the cmd window, you should be able to see anything fishy going on. If you're running it in some other way… well, maybe you're doing something wrong, but we can't diagnose it if you don't tell us what you're doing.

Comment: I am using python in a cygwin terminal "python fail.py".  I can run other python programs, even ones linking dll's in similar ways.  I will try it with the -v flag and see if anything interesting comes out.

Comment: Also, if you run just this stripped-down program, does it exhibit the same behavior? (I ask partly because I had an amazingly stupid bug in my own code recently where I did the `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` bit _inside `main()`_ with predictable consequences…)

Comment: OK, the cygwin shell shouldn't be any different from the cmd shell, except for the name of the interpreter program. The point is, you just type `python myscript.py` and it runs the script 6 times in a row?

Comment: @abarnert, this is the output of the above code.  Running python with the -v flag gets the same output in the stdout, and a ton of import noise from numpy, nothing notable however.  When I > the stdout and 2> the standard error, I get only 1 copy of each of the outputs.

Comment: So `camera.py_SaperaCamera` is doing a lot of complicated `numpy` stuff, and possibly some native C code, and who knows what else. It seems pretty clear that the problem is in that `camera` library. Unless you're doing something silly like calling the interpreter recursively, my first guess would be that you're trampling on the stack. But regardless, the best way to debug it is the usual binary triangulation: strip half the code out of `camera` until it stops happening, then add half the code back in until it occurs, etc.

Comment: Wow.  So when I run it in the usual cmd terminal, I get a crash, and "Windows is checking for a soultion . . ." box.  No restart . . .

Any thoughts on what cygwin id b0rking up here?

Comment: OK, that just reaffirms my guess. You're trampling on either stack, or the interpreter's heap structures, from your C code. (It _could_ be from `numpy` code, if you've somehow gotten `numpy` to believe that part of the stack is a buffer that it should use as an array, but that seems less likely.) The fact that this happens to result in jumping back to the start of the script instead of segfaulting or making your computer come to life and eat your cat or whatever is probably just some unusual but not impossible dumb luck, and not really meaningful.

Comment: @abarnert Well, I accepted from the get-go that something was broken in that module.  The thing that is still weird to me is the multiple-launch of cygwin.  It is also strange to me that it seems to run differently in cygwin than the cmd shell.  Drilling into that more shortly.

Comment: @meawoppl: Well, often two trivially different builds will do different things with the same stack corruption. Especially since native Windows and cygwin have different ways to protect against stack corruption (because it can be used for exploits). Meanwhile, remember that C stack frames are where return values are kept—and that Python compounds things by using the C stack for Python frames. So it's actually not _that_ implausible that scribbling over the stack could cause a jump to the start of your program in the interpreter, the start of the interpreter state itself, etc.

Comment: Running the native Windows Python inside the VC++ debugger, or just looking at its crash dump, or running the cygwin one inside gdb, might help diagnose the problem, if you understand how the interpreter works. Otherwise, treat it as an entertaining red herring that isn't going to help you fix your real problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22342/discussion-between-meawoppl-and-abarnert)

Answer (score 1):

Why not comment out `cam = py_SaperaCamera.Camera()`? Then you'd know if it's instantiation of your Camera class that's messing smth up. This could narrow your area of search for the problem.